# Optimizing execution time and exploring closed form solutions in Mathematica's DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, functions, performance-tuning, function-construction

I am encountering two issues while running the following code in Mathematica:

**Slow execution:** I have been running the code for approximately 30 minutes, but it is still executing. I am using Windows 64-bit with Mathematica version 13.2.1.0. Is there any way to optimize this code to make it run faster? Are there any specific techniques or alternative functions that I can utilize to expedite the execution time?

**Closed form solutions:** Additionally, I would like to inquire if it is possible to obtain closed form solutions for the functions `m[t], n[t], p[t], and q[t]` within the given set of equations.

```
equations = {
   m'[t] == 1/a (r3 + n[t] - q[t] - (r1 + r2) m[t]),
   n'[t] == -(1/b) m[t],
   p'[t] == 1/c (m[t] - r4),
   q[t] == p[t] + (m[t] - r4) r5,
   m[0] == m0,(*Initial condition for m(t)*)
   n[0] == n0,(*Initial condition for n(t)*)
   p[0] == p0   (*Initial condition for p(t)*)};

sol = DSolve[equations, {m, n, p, q}, t]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system as presented to `DSolve` consists of autonomous linear DEs plus an algebraic equation that on the surface depend on each other. Consequently, `DSolve` seems unable to take advantage of the simplicity of the autonomous linear system and applies a DAE solver instead.

Here's an approach: Eliminate the algebraic equation for `q[t]`, solve the linear DE system, and construct the solution for `q` from the solution to the linear system and the formula for `q`:

```
equations = {
   m'[t] == 1/a (r3 + n[t] - (p[t] + (m[t] - r4) r5 ) - (r1 + r2) m[t]),
   n'[t] == -(1/b) m[t],
   p'[t] == 1/c (m[t] - r4),
   
   m[0] == m0,  (*Initial condition for m(t)*)
   n[0] == n0,  (*Initial condition for n(t)*)
   p[0] == p0   (*Initial condition for p(t)*)};

sol = Append[#, q -> Function @@ {t, p[t] + (m[t] - r4) r5 /. #}] & /@
   DSolve[equations, {m, n, p}, t] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {69.7276, <1.7 MB output>} *)
```

Quite a bit faster than the 30+ min. reported in the OP.

---

*Update 1: A faster `DSolve[]`*

We can reduce the number of parameters and simplify the formulas. This makes a marked improved, much more than I would have expected.

```
{bmat, amat} = CoefficientArrays[
   First@SolveValues[equations[[;; 3]], D[Through[{m, n, p}[t]], t]],
   Through[{m, n, p}[t]]
   ];

idx = 0;
reducedAmat = 
  Replace[Normal@amat,
   x_ /; ! PossibleZeroQ[x] :> $a[++idx], {2}];
backsub = Simplify@
  DeleteCases[
   Thread[Flatten@reducedAmat -> Flatten@Normal@amat], 
   HoldPattern[0 -> 0]];
(* simplification (by inspection): *)
reducedAmat = reducedAmat /. $a[3] -> -$a[2];

(*ClearSystemCache[]*)(* clear caches for valid timing *)
DSolve[
 {D[{m[t], n[t], p[t]}, t] == 
      reducedAmat . {m[t], n[t], p[t]} + bmat, 
  equations[[4 ;;]]},
 {m[t], n[t], p[t]}, t] /. 
   backsub // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {2.46386, < 0.9 MB output >}  *)
```

---

*Update 2: Comment on `MatrixExp[]` solutions*

Aside from lacking working code, the answer from @RolandF has a perhaps subtle mathematical error.

The general matrix exponential solution to $\dot {\bf y}(t) = {\bf A} \mathbin{.} {\bf y}(t) + {\bf b(t)}$ has the form
$${\bf y}(t)=\Psi(t) \mathbin{.}\left({\bf y}(0)+\int_0^t \Psi(-t) \mathbin{.} {\bf b}(t) \; dt\right) \,,\quad \Psi(t) = \exp({\bf A}\,t)$$
When $\bf b$ is constant and $\bf A$ is invertible, this is easily simplified to a solution resembling @RolandF's in outline; however, $\bf A$ is not invertible in the OP's linear system. And since one of the basis functions of the  solution space to the homogeneous system is constant (eigenvalue $0$) and $\bf b$ is constant, the situation is equivalent to having a repeated eigenvalue. There is no way to avoid the integral (or a calculation equivalent to it, since the integral would be simple were it not for the numerous parameters making superficially complicated).

```
{bmat, amat} = CoefficientArrays[
   First@SolveValues[equations[[;; 3]], D[Through[{m, n, p}[t]], t]],
   Through[{m, n, p}[t]]
   ];

psi = MatrixExp[amat t] // Simplify; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.79531, Null}  *)

msol = psi . ({m0, n0, p0} + # - (# /. t -> 0) &@
      Integrate[(psi /. t -> -t) . bmat, t]); //
    AbsoluteTiming
(*  {4.77207, Null}  *)
    
msol // ByteCount
(*  158312  *)

(* put in solution form *)
matexpsol = 
  Thread[{m, n, p} -> (Function[t, #] & /@
   Transpose@ msol)];
matexpsol = 
   Append[matexpsol, 
      q -> Function @@ {t, p[t] + (m[t] - r4) r5 /. matexpsol}];

matexpsol // ByteCount
(*  262976  *)
```

If we use `reduceAmat` as in *Update 1*,
we reduce the times above to a little less than half,
which is about as fast `DSolve` in *Update 1*.

If you worry about the use of the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute `msol`, one can, at some cost of time, compute the definite integral:

```
msol = psi . ({m0, n0, p0} + 
      Integrate[(psi /. t -> -t) . bmat, {t, 0, t}]); //
    AbsoluteTiming
(*  {25.6736, Null}  *)
```

The result is equivalent (applying `Simplify` to the difference of the two yields `0`).

---

*Update 3: Alternative conversion to linear system*

Another way to convert the DAE system to a linear ODE system is to differentiate the equation for `q[t]`.  `DSolve` computes the solution in about a minute, about as fast as the first solution, but the solution here is much larger in size.

```
equations3 = {
   m'[t] == 
    1/a (r3 + n[t] - (p[t] + (m[t] - r4) r5) - (r1 + r2) m[t]), 
   n'[t] == -(1/b) m[t], p'[t] == 1/c (m[t] - r4),
   D[q[t] == p[t] + (m[t] - r4) r5, t],
   m[0] == m0,(*Initial condition for m(t)*)
   n[0] == n0,(*Initial condition for n(t)*)
   p[0] == p0,   (*Initial condition for p(t)*)
   q[t] == p[t] + (m[t] - r4) r5 /. t -> 0};

PrintTemporary@Dynamic@Clock@Infinity;
DSolve[equations3, {m, n, p, q}, t] // ByteCount // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {64.1766, 5816160}  *)
```

Comment: very nice and complete solutions. I'll wait for a bit more time before giving the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

The set of equations

```
equations = 
   {m'[t] == 1/a (r3 + n[t] - q[t] - (r1 + r2) m[t]), 
   n'[t] == -(1/b) m[t], p'[t] == 1/c (m[t] - r4), 
   q[t] == p[t] + (m[t] - r4) r5, 
   m[0] == m0,(*Initial condition for m(t)*)
   n[0] == n0,(*Initial condition for n(t)*)
   p[0] == p0   (*Initial condition for p(t)*)};
```

boils down to a linear equations of first order for three unkown functions

```
MatrixForm[ 
equations3 = 
Collect[{m'[t] == 1/a (r3 + n[t] - q[t] - (r1 + r2) m[t]),
n'[t] == -(1/b) m[t],p'[t] == 1/c (m[t] - r4)} /. 
{q -> ( p[#] + (m[#] - r4) r5 &)} //FullSimplify, 
{m[t], n[t], p[t]}]]
```

In tradtional form

$$\partial_t 
\left(\begin{array}{c}
 m \\
 n \\
 p \\
\end{array}\right)
 =\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{\text{r1}+\text{r2}+\text{r5}}{a} & \frac{1}{a} & -\frac{1}{a} \\
 -\frac{1}{b} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{c} & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 m \\
 n \\
 p \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{\text{r3}+\text{r4} \text{r5}}{a} \\
 0 \\
 -\frac{\text{r4}}{c} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Quite generally, any non-homogenous linear equation with constant coefficients has as solution the constant solution with `x' ==0`  plus the general solution of the homogenous equation, it is the exponential of the constant factor. that can be a matrix if x is a vector

```
   DSolve[x'[t] == a  x[t] + b, x[t], t]

    {{x[t]->-(b/a)+E^(a t) Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]}}
```

The `Eigensystem` of the matrix yields the three (two) frequencies, that multiply the time variable `t` in the exponentials. The solution has three free constants C[1],C[2],C[3] to be adapted to fit the start conditions.

The expression are indefinitely long by a blow up of the different forms of the square roots in the Eigenvalue.  Try to replace all the expressions multiplying the time variable t by a frequency $\pm \omega$, there is only one, because one eigenvalue is 0.

The starting point is

```
   dsol = DSolveValue[equations, {m[t], n[t], p[t]}, t];
```

The structure of the  solutions can be inspected by setting two constants to zero.

```
 dsol1 /. {C[2] :> 0, C[3] :> 0};
```

The frequencies can be determined by

```
Cases[dsol1, t*__, \[Infinity]] // Flatten//Simplify // Union
```

Alternatively the solutions can be  determined in the direct way

```
 x' = A x + b  ;  xspec= Solve[ A x == b,x],   xgen = MatrixExp[A (t-t0]] . x[t0]
```

Comment: +1 and thanks for the nice idea.